# Need help setting up simple Virtual Directory in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, virtual, pool

Noobie question...

Using IIS7, I am trying to create a virtual directory for the folder that contains my video files, but can't get my head around how it is done.

For example...
The existing address is http://www.mydomain.com/members
which points to C:\wwwroot\mydomain\members
I need http://www.mydomain.com/flash-members to point to the same path.

The existing IIS path to the members folder is Server\Sites\www_mydomain_com\members (has application icon)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example, assuming www_mydomain_com is the Site (little world icon), you can do this by:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Right-click the web site, select Add Virtual Directory
3. In the Alias field, enter flash-members
4. In the Physical Path field, enter your path (C:\wwwroot\mydomain\members)

Comment: Hi Ryan. Thanks for your reply. I did exactly what you suggest, but the path still doesn't resolve (404). Do I need to restart IIS or anything to make it work?

Comment: Restarting the IIS Admin Service didn't help.

Comment: @Rick I don't receive 404 when doing this. Are you using the correct port/protocol in your browser when attempting to view it? Instead of opening the browser and typing the URL, try using the Browse link on the right hand Actions pane.

If that doesn't work, there may be some other configuration issue. How simple is the site? Perhaps you could try a simple example web site and compare the two.

Comment: This is a client's adult site so the address I am providing in here is not the real address. Using IIS to browse (there are two links) http://web3.beta.mydomain.com/flash-members/ works great but the correct address http://www.mydomain.com/flash-members doesn't. 'web3.beta' is replaced with www in the public url.

Comment: When you are creating the virtual directory, does the Test Settings... button give you any hints?

Is it in the same IIS Site? If not, are the bindings for the second (virtual directory) site configured correctly?

Comment: Using the path that works, I am able to get on with my mission, which is a little complicated. I am configuring the H264 Streaming Module. This module allows a video to be played at a section that is yet to be downloaded. However, adding the module to the entire site disables iPhones from viewing the videos. A way around this is suggested at [link](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/discussion/topic/224#message1154). However, I have just discovered that adding the module's Handler Mapping to 'flash-members' also adds it to the regular 'members'. Argh! How do I do this?

Comment: To answer your last question, the results of Test Settings is exactly the same as the existing 'members' folder. The 'members' folder appears to be an Application (globe over page icon) and is in the application pool while the 'flash-members' folder a regular virtual folder (looks like a shortcut icon). The bindings are identical.

Comment: Can you prefix the module mapping request path with /members/?

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks! Would setting up a sub-domain, as discussed here help? [link](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/discussion/topic/224?discussion_action=add;message=1154#message1154) Would this avoid the web.config issue? Not sure what you mean by "prefix the module mapping".

Comment: I can't start a chat (low rep)

Comment: When you add the module mapping, in the Request path field, enter /members/* instead of just *. If you set up a sub-domain, but it is mapped to the same IIS site, you'll have the same issues you're having now (the virtual directory uses the web.config from the physical path, not a separate one).

Comment: I see what you mean. Do you mean '/flash-members/*.mp4'? I was previously entering *.mp4 in that field. Will that work for all the sub-folder's contents too? Testing it now...

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. It didn't like the new Request path (ignored it). Thanks so much for your help and time on this Ryan. Much appreciated!